# Laravel 4 dynamic model call

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing an API to acces some data on my database. I'm creating a controller for each part of the API. For example, I will have a controller to attend API calls to get a film list (FilmsController) and other controller to attend API calls to get a director list (DirectorsController)

Each controller will have a basic set of methods (getList, getInfo) so I made an ApiController to use as the base for the others. In the ApiController I have the basic set of methods but I have to call the models in non very polite way.

I'm I missing something? Is there any other way to call the models dynamically? I'm using the controllers wrong?

Here is the code, thanks.

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

    protected $model = '';

    public function getList() 
    {
        $items = call_user_func(array($this->model,'all'));
        return Response::json($items);
    }
    ...
```

}

And the FilmsController

```
class FilmsController extends ApiController {

    protected $model = 'Film';

}
```

Am I going with a bad design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to bind model to controller, it would be better to use Laravel IoC container and its automatic resolution feature.

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

    protected $model;

    public function getList() 
    {
        $items = $this->model->all();
        return Response::json($items);
    }
}

class FilmsController extends ApiController {

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

Find more about this in [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#automatic-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

why you call model using variable and use `call_user_func`  function

you can just create ApiController as abstract class and you override the basic set of methods (getList, getInfo) into FilmsController and DirectorsController then you can use Film Model

ApiController:

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {


    public function getList() 
    {
    }
```

FilmsController:

```
class FilmsController extends ApiController {

                public function getList() 
                {
                   $items = Film::all();
                   return Response::json($items);


                }

        }
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to implement the getList method for each case, I want to have an "standard" set of methods for every api section. That's why I created the ApiController. The @cheelahim answer is what I was looking for. Thank you both.